# How can I know which exceptions might be thrown from a method call?

Tags: python, exception

Is there a way knowing (at coding time) which exceptions to expect when executing python code?

I end up catching the base Exception class 90% of the time since I don't know which exception type might be thrown (reading the documentation doesn't always help, since many times an exception can be propagated from the deep. And many times the documentation is not updated or correct).

Is there some kind of tool to check this (like by reading the Python code and libs)?

Comment: Bear in mind that in Python < 2.6, you can `raise` strings as well, not just `BaseException` subclasses.  So if you're calling into library code that is out of your control, even `except Exception` is not sufficient, since it won't catch string exceptions.  As others have pointed out, you're barking up the wrong tree here.

Comment: I didn't know that. I thought except Exception:.. catches almost everything.

Comment: `except Exception` works fine for catching string exceptions in Python 2.6 and later.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I guess a solution could be only imprecise because of lack of static typing rules.

I'm not aware of some tool that checks exceptions, but you could come up with your own tool matching your needs (a good chance to play a little with static analysis).

As a first attempt, you could write a function that builds an AST, finds all `Raise` nodes, and then tries to figure out common patterns of raising exceptions (e. g. calling a constructor directly)

Let `x` be the following program:

```
x = '''\
if f(x):
    raise IOError(errno.ENOENT, 'not found')
else:
    e = g(x)
    raise e
'''
```

Build the AST using the `compiler` package:

```
tree = compiler.parse(x)
```

Then define a `Raise` visitor class:

```
class RaiseVisitor(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.nodes = []
    def visitRaise(self, n):
        self.nodes.append(n)
```

And walk the AST collecting `Raise` nodes:

```
v = RaiseVisitor()
compiler.walk(tree, v)

>>> print v.nodes
[
    Raise(
        CallFunc(
            Name('IOError'),
            [Getattr(Name('errno'), 'ENOENT'), Const('not found')],
            None, None),
        None, None),
    Raise(Name('e'), None, None),
]
```

You may continue by resolving symbols using compiler symbol tables, analyzing data dependencies, etc. Or you may just deduce, that `CallFunc(Name('IOError'), ...)` "should definitely mean raising `IOError`", which is quite OK for quick practical results :)

Comment: Thanks for this interesting answer. Didn't understand though why should I look for something more other than all the raise nodes. Why should I "resolving symbols using compiler symbol tables, analyzing data dependencies"? Isn't the only way to raise exception is by raise() ?

Comment: Given the `v.nodes` value above, you cannot actually say, what the thing is `Name('IOError')` or `Name('e')`. You don't know what value(s) those `IOError` and `e` can point to, as they are so-called free variables. Even if their binding context were known (here symbol tables come into play), you should perform some kind of data dependency analysis to infer their exact values (this should be hard in Python).

Comment: As you are looking for a practical semi-automated solution, a list of `['IOError(errno.ENOENT, "not found")', 'e']` displayed to the user is just fine. But you cannot infer actual classes of values of variables represented by strings :) (sorry for reposting)

Comment: Yes. This method, though clever, doesn't actually give you a complete coverage.  Due to Python's dynamic nature, it is perfectly possible (though obviously a bad idea) for code you're calling into to do something like `exc_class = raw_input(); exec "raise " + exc_class`.  The point is that this kind of static analysis is not truly possible in a dynamic language like Python.

Comment: Ok. I guess that based on the code above, a simple, not very accurate analyzer can be developed. It might not be perfect but it would help in many cases to at least hint about possible exceptions from the deep

Comment: By the way, you can just `find /path/to/library -name '*.py' | grep 'raise '` to get similar results :)

Comment: I really hoped for some kind of automated tool. I really like Java's way of this.

Comment: What's an AST ?

Comment: Note that `compiler` is now deprecated. The `ast` package should be used instead. I don't know if there is still an explicit `visitRaise` function, but you can achieve the same with `isinstance(n, ast.Raise)` by subclassing `ast.NodeVisitor` and implement `visit(self, n: ast.AST)`.

Answer (score 25):

You should only catch exceptions that you will handle.

Catching all exceptions by their concrete types is nonsense.  You should catch specific exceptions you *can* and *will* handle.  For other exceptions, you may write a generic catch that catches "base Exception", logs it (use `str()` function) and terminates your program (or does something else that's appropriate in a crashy situation).

If you really gonna handle *all* exceptions and are sure none of them are fatal (for example, if you're running the code in some kind of a sandboxed environment), then your approach of catching generic BaseException fits your aims.

You might be also interested in [language exception reference](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.BaseException), not a reference for the library you're using.

If the library reference is really poor and it doesn't re-throw its own exceptions when catching system ones, **the only useful approach is to run tests** (maybe add it to test suite, because if something is undocumented, it may change!).  Delete a file crucial for your code and check what exception is being thrown.  Supply too much data and check what error it yields.

You will have to run tests anyway, since, even **if the method of getting the exceptions by source code existed, it wouldn't give you any idea how you should handle any of those**.  Maybe you should be showing error message "File needful.txt is not found!" when you catch `IndexError`?  Only test can tell.

Comment: Sure, But how can one decide which exceptions he should handle if he doesn't know what might be thrown ??

Comment: @bugspy.net , fixed my answer to reflect this matter

Comment: Maybe it's time for source code analyzer that can find out this? Shouldn't be too hard to develop i think

Comment: @bugspy.net , I emboldened the clause why it might not be the time for it.

Comment: Sure you are right. However it may still be interesting - during development - to know which types of exceptions may occur.

Answer (score 17):

The correct tool to solve this problem is unittests. If you are having exceptions raised by real code that the unittests do not raise, then you need more unittests.

Consider this

```
def f(duck):
    try:
        duck.quack()
    except ??? could be anything
```

duck can be any object

Obviously you can have an `AttributeError` if duck has no quack, a `TypeError` if duck has a quack but it is not callable. You have no idea what `duck.quack()` might raise though, maybe even a `DuckError` or something

Now supposing you have code like this

```
arr[i] = get_something_from_database()
```

If it raises an `IndexError` you don't know whether it has come from arr[i] or from deep inside the database function. usually it doesn't matter so much where the exception occurred, rather that something went wrong and what you wanted to happen didn't happen.

A handy technique is to catch and maybe reraise the exception like this

```
except Exception as e
    #inspect e, decide what to do
    raise
```

Comment: Why catch it at all if you are going to "reraise" it?

Comment: You don't _have_ to reraise it, that is what the comment was supposed to indicate.

Comment: You may also choose to log the exception somewhere and then reraise

Comment: I don't think that writing unit tests is the answer. The question is "how can I find out which exceptions to expect" and writing unit tests will not help you find this out.  In fact, in order to write the unit test you already have to know which exceptions to expect so in order to write a correct unit test you have to anser the original question as well.

Answer (score 9):

Noone explained so far, why you can't have a full, 100% correct list of exceptions, so I thought it's worth commenting on. One of the reasons is a first-class function. Let's say that you have a function like this:

```
def apl(f,arg):
   return f(arg)
```

Now `apl` can raise any exception that `f` raises. While there are not many functions like that in the core library, anything that uses list comprehension with custom filters, map, reduce, etc. are affected.

The documentation and the source analysers are the only "serious" sources of information here. Just keep in mind what they cannot do.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this when using socket, I wanted to find out all the error conditions I would run in to (so rather than trying to create errors and figure out what socket does I just wanted a concise list). Ultimately I ended up grep'ing "/usr/lib64/python2.4/test/test_socket.py" for "raise":

```
$ grep raise test_socket.py
Any exceptions raised by the clients during their tests
        raise TypeError, "test_func must be a callable function"
    raise NotImplementedError, "clientSetUp must be implemented."
    def raise_error(*args, **kwargs):
        raise socket.error
    def raise_herror(*args, **kwargs):
        raise socket.herror
    def raise_gaierror(*args, **kwargs):
        raise socket.gaierror
    self.failUnlessRaises(socket.error, raise_error,
    self.failUnlessRaises(socket.error, raise_herror,
    self.failUnlessRaises(socket.error, raise_gaierror,
        raise socket.error
    # Check that setting it to an invalid value raises ValueError
    # Check that setting it to an invalid type raises TypeError
    def raise_timeout(*args, **kwargs):
    self.failUnlessRaises(socket.timeout, raise_timeout,
    def raise_timeout(*args, **kwargs):
    self.failUnlessRaises(socket.timeout, raise_timeout,
```

Which is a pretty concise list of errors. Now of course this only works on a case by case basis and depends on the tests being accurate (which they usually are). Otherwise you need to pretty much catch all exceptions, log them and dissect them and figure out how to handle them (which with unit testing wouldn't be to difficult).

Comment: This strengthen my argument, that exception handling in Python is very problematic, if we need to use grep or source analyzers to deal with something so basic (which for example in java existed from day one. Sometimes verbosity is a good thing. Java is verbose but at least there are no nasty surprises)

Comment: @GabiMe, It's not like this ability (or static typing in general) is a silver bullet to prevent all bugs. Java is _full_ of nasty surprises. That's why eclipse regularly crashes.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways that I found informative. The first one, run the code in iPython, which will display the exception type.

```
n = 2
str = 'me '
str + 2
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

In the second way we settle for catching too much and improve on it over time. Include a `try` expression in your code and catch `except Exception as err`. Print sufficient data to know what exception was thrown. As exceptions are thrown improve your code by adding a more precise `except` clause. When you feel that you have caught all relevant exceptions remove the all inclusive one. A good thing to do anyway because it swallows programming errors.

```
try:
   so something
except Exception as err:
   print "Some message"
   print err.__class__
   print err
   exit(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

normally, you'd need to catch exception only around a few lines of code. You wouldn't want to put your whole `main` function into the `try except` clause. for every few line you always should now (or be able easily to check) what kind of exception might be raised.

docs have an exhaustive [list of built-in exceptions](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/exceptions.html). don't try to except those exception that you're not expecting, they might be handled/expected in the calling code.

**edit**: what might be thrown depends on obviously on what you're doing! accessing random element of a sequence: `IndexError`, random element of a dict: `KeyError`, etc.

Just try to run those few lines in IDLE and cause an exception. But unittest would be a better solution, naturally.

Comment: This not answering my simple question. I don't ask on how to design my exception handling, or when or how to catch. I ask how to find out what might be thrown

Comment: @bugspy.net: It is **impossible** to do what you ask, and this is a perfectly valid workaround.

Answer (score 0):

This is a copy and pasted answer I wrote for [How to list all exceptions a function could raise in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32560116/how-to-list-all-exceptions-a-function-could-raise-in-python-3/), I hope that is allowed.

> I needed to do something similar and found this post. I decided I
> would write a little library to help.
>
> Say hello to [Deep-AST](https://github.com/DontShaveTheYak/deep-ast). It's very early alpha but it is [pip
> installable](https://pypi.org/project/deep-ast/). It has all of the limitations mentioned in this post
> and some additional ones but its already off to a really good start.
>
> For example when parsing `HTTPConnection.getresponse()` from
> `http.client` it parses `24489` AST Nodes. It finds `181` total raised
> Exceptions (this includes duplicates) and `8` unique Exceptions were
> raised. A [working code example](https://github.com/DontShaveTheYak/deep-ast/blob/main/tests/test_http_client.py).
>
> The biggest flaw is this it currently does work with a bare `raise`:
>
> ```
> def foo():
>
>     try:
>         bar()
>     except TypeError:
>         raise
> ```
>
> But I think this will be easy to solve and I plan on fixing it.
>
> The library can handle more than just figuring out exceptions, what
> about listing all Parent classes? It can [handle that](https://github.com/DontShaveTheYak/deep-ast/blob/2a7f3d21e64e965540e125a2758c3e6622ee64aa/tests/test_classes.py#L145-L196) too!

Comment: Nice find, but it seems to run into max recursion depth errors at least when I try it on my machine for something like `shutil.rmtree()` see https://github.com/DontShaveTheYak/deep-ast/issues/36