# can I do assumptions on an exception.errno in python?

Tags: python, exception

I know, I could workaround it with a different type, but I hope the question could be interesting anyhow...

```
def try_me:
    try:
        do_something()
        return 0 # can it be confused with an error?
    except some_external_module.defined_exception as e:
        return e.errno
    except:
        return -1
```

In other words, is there any rule or convention that says err numbers shall be strictly positive?

Comment: Why would it matter either way?

Comment: There's a convention that 0 means "no error" and any non-zero integer (positive or negative) means "some error with this code occurred", but the convention in Python is to use _classes_ (objects) as exceptions, not integers and error tables.

Comment: thanks everybody, found something related here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1591319/2787591