# How to list all exceptions a function could raise in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.4

Is there a programmatic way to get a list of all exceptions a function could raise?

I know for example that [`os.makedirs(path[, mode])`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.html?highlight=os#os.makedirs) can raise `PermissionError` (and maybe others), but the documentation only mentions [`OSError`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/exceptions.html#OSError). (This is just an example - maybe even a bad one; I am not especially interested in this function - more in the problem in general).

Is there a programmatic way to find all the possible exceptions when they are not/poorly documented? This may be especially useful in 3rd-party libraries and libraries that do not ship with Python source code.

The solution presented in "[Python: How can I know which exceptions might be thrown from a method call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591319/python-how-can-i-know-which-exceptions-might-be-thrown-from-a-method-call)" does not work in Python 3; there is no [`compiler`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/compiler.html) package.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: How can I know which exceptions might be thrown from a method call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591319/python-how-can-i-know-which-exceptions-might-be-thrown-from-a-method-call)

Comment: Do you want to know this at coding time, or run time?

Comment: "there is no [`compiler`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/compiler.html) package." Then as suggested into your link use the [`parser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/parser.html#module-parser) one. Or the [`compile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=compile#compile) builtin or the [`ast.parse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.parse) function

Comment: in order to use the method described there i'd need to have the classes `Name`, `Raise`, `CallFunc`, `Const`, `Getattr` from the `compiler` package. where would i find those?

Comment: i found `Call`, `Name` and `Raise` in the `_ast` module. i'll see what i can do from there.

Comment: I don't think you _can_ get a guaranteed-complete list for arbitrary code, unless that list can include some kind of wildcard value.  Nothing stops a function from executing a statement like `raise user_provided_callable('Ouch!')` or `raise CONFIG['exceptions'].get('nitpick', ValueError)('Whoops!')`.  That kind of thing might even be a good idea in some situations, although I'm struggling to think of any beyond, "Because I could!".

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase not to mention built-in exceptions like NameError, KeyError or any other exception that propagates from a function call. Finding the complete list of a function is very likely to be reduceable to halting problem.

Comment: I am a little confused by the question - you say that `os.makedirs` can raise `FileExistsError` - but as far as I can see it actually swallows `FileExistsError` [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/os.py#L232).

Comment: you are right `FileExistsError` does not belong to the exceptions `makedirs` can rasie. my mistake. i corrected it in the question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can't get reliable results for some (if not most) functions. Some examples:

- functions that execute arbitrary code (e.g. `exec(')(rorrEeulaV esiar'[::-1])` raises `ValueError`)
- functions that aren't written in Python
- functions that call other functions that can propagate errors to the caller
- functions re-raising active exceptions in the `except:` block

Unfortunately, this list is incomplete.

E.g. `os.makedirs` is written in Python and you can see its source:

```
...
try:
    mkdir(name, mode)
except OSError as e:
    if not exist_ok or e.errno != errno.EEXIST or not path.isdir(name):
        raise
```

Bare `raise` re-raises the last active exception (`OSError` or one of its subclasses). Here's the [class hierarchy for `OSError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy):

```
+-- OSError
|    +-- BlockingIOError
|    +-- ChildProcessError
|    +-- ConnectionError
|    |    +-- BrokenPipeError
|    |    +-- ConnectionAbortedError
|    |    +-- ConnectionRefusedError
|    |    +-- ConnectionResetError
|    +-- FileExistsError
|    +-- FileNotFoundError
|    +-- InterruptedError
|    +-- IsADirectoryError
|    +-- NotADirectoryError
|    +-- PermissionError
|    +-- ProcessLookupError
|    +-- TimeoutError
```

To get the exact exception types you'll need to look into `mkdir`, functions it calls, functions those functions call etc.

So, *getting possible exceptions without running the function is **very** hard* and you really should not do it.

---

However for simple cases like

```
raise Exception # without arguments
raise Exception('abc') # with arguments
```

a combination of [`ast` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) functionality and [`inspect.getclosurevars`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getclosurevars) (to get exception classes, was introduced in Python 3.3) can produce quite accurate results:

```
from inspect import getclosurevars, getsource
from collections import ChainMap
from textwrap import dedent
import ast, os

class MyException(Exception):
    pass

def g():
    raise Exception

class A():
    def method():
        raise OSError

def f(x):
    int()
    A.method()
    os.makedirs()
    g()
    raise MyException
    raise ValueError('argument')


def get_exceptions(func, ids=set()):
    try:
        vars = ChainMap(*getclosurevars(func)[:3])
        source = dedent(getsource(func))
    except TypeError:
        return

    class _visitor(ast.NodeTransformer):
        def __init__(self):
            self.nodes = []
            self.other = []

        def visit_Raise(self, n):
            self.nodes.append(n.exc)

        def visit_Expr(self, n):
            if not isinstance(n.value, ast.Call):
                return
            c, ob = n.value.func, None
            if isinstance(c, ast.Attribute):
                parts = []
                while getattr(c, 'value', None):
                    parts.append(c.attr)
                    c = c.value
                if c.id in vars:
                    ob = vars[c.id]
                    for name in reversed(parts):
                        ob = getattr(ob, name)

            elif isinstance(c, ast.Name):
                if c.id in vars:
                    ob = vars[c.id]

            if ob is not None and id(ob) not in ids:
                self.other.append(ob)
                ids.add(id(ob))

    v = _visitor()
    v.visit(ast.parse(source))
    for n in v.nodes:
        if isinstance(n, (ast.Call, ast.Name)):
            name = n.id if isinstance(n, ast.Name) else n.func.id
            if name in vars:
                yield vars[name]

    for o in v.other:
        yield from get_exceptions(o)


for e in get_exceptions(f):
    print(e)
```

prints

```
<class '__main__.MyException'>
<class 'ValueError'>
<class 'OSError'>
<class 'Exception'>
```

Keep in mind that this code only works for functions written in Python.

Comment: this looks very nice! i tried `get_exceptions(os.makedirs)` - there it returns nothing.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist This is because of the implementation of `os.makedirs`.  It uses a bare `raise` in a [block where `OSError` is caught](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/os.py#L242).  Because of the bare `raise` (I think), you never get `name == 'OSError'` in the code above. `OSError` is actually in the `vars` ChainMap in the code above), but not the actual subclasses of `OSError` that might be thrown, I think.  Possibly, you could recurse using `getclosurevars` as you visit the `ast` tree, but I'm not even sure that would get everything.

Comment: @vaultah In python3.11, `OSError: could not get source code` occurs, where it is supposed to be a `<class 'Exception'>`.

Answer (score 4):

### Finding Exception in non built-in source code:

As said in the topic [Python: How can I know which exceptions might be thrown from a method call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591319/python-how-can-i-know-which-exceptions-might-be-thrown-from-a-method-call), you can get the Abstract Syntax Tree and search for raised exceptions.

```
import ast

def find_raise(body):
    raises = []
    for ast_ in body:
        if isinstance(ast_, ast.Raise):
            raises.append(ast_)
        if hasattr(ast_, 'body'):
            raises += find_raise(ast_.body)
    return list(set(raises))


test = '''
def f(arg):
    raise OSError(arg)
'''

raises = find_raise(ast.parse(test).body)
print [i.type.func.id for i in raises] # print ['OSError']
```

This method works for every piece of code that you have written.

---

### Finding Exception in Built-in methods

You *cannot* parse built-in function like `os.makedirs`.

Two alternatives:

- You can have a look at the tests included in your python distribution ([ex with cpython](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Lib/test/test_os.py#l1012))
- and if your target method offers python source code, you can parse it like previously (the code would be in /usr/lib/python3/*.py)

For all native C methods, you are stuck with the documentation and should trust it. When `os.makedirs` says it only returns `OSError`, it is true, since `PermissionError` and `FileExistError` exceptions  are subclasses of `OSError`.

To find Errors programmatically for built-in you can use this example:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\w+Error', open.__doc__)
['IOError', 'FileExistsError', 'ValueError']
>>> re.findall(r'\w+Error', os.makedirs.__doc__)
['OSError']
```

It catches all exceptions with a name ending with 'Error', it surely can be extended to find all standard exceptions.

Comment: 'cannot parse built-in function' i was afraid of that; `PermissionError` is nowhere to be found in `os.py`. i will have a look at your solution. thanks!

Comment: Notice that `PermissionError` and `FileExistError` exceptions are subclasses of `OSError`. So you should be fine **only** catching `OSError` and filtering after if needed.

Comment: true; but i'd still need to know about the existence of these exceptions.

Comment: I added an example to find exception form doc. This is not highly accurate but its a good start...

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do something similar and found this post. I decided I would write a little library to help.

Say hello to [Deep-AST](https://github.com/DontShaveTheYak/deep-ast). It's very early alpha but it is [pip installable](https://pypi.org/project/deep-ast/). It has all of the limitations mentioned in this post and some additional ones but its already off to a really good start.

For example when parsing `HTTPConnection.getresponse()` from `http.client` it parses `24489` AST Nodes. It finds `181` total raised Exceptions (this includes duplicates) and `8` unique Exceptions were raised. A [working code example](https://github.com/DontShaveTheYak/deep-ast/blob/main/tests/test_http_client.py).

The biggest flaw is this it currently does work with a bare `raise`:

```
def foo():

    try:
        bar()
    except TypeError:
        raise
```

But I think this will be easy to solve and I plan on fixing it.

The library can handle more than just figuring out exceptions, what about listing all Parent classes? It can [handle that](https://github.com/DontShaveTheYak/deep-ast/blob/2a7f3d21e64e965540e125a2758c3e6622ee64aa/tests/test_classes.py#L145-L196) too!

Comment: thanks for that! that may come in handy!