# How to find all the possible exceptions raised by float()

Tags: python

I know that `float("foo")` could raise a `ValueError`, so I wrote my method as follows:

```py
def cast_to_float(value: str) -> float:
    try:
        return float(value)
    except ValueError as e:
        # deal with it
```

However, I've just realized that `float()` can also raise an `OverflowError`. So I'm wondering whether there are other types of exceptions I am not catching. I understand that using `except Exception` is a bad practice.

How can I find all the exception types that `float()` can raise?

I have tried [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=float#float) as well as the *“Go to Definition”* menu of my IDE, but I can't find where the exceptions are raised.

Comment: Did you read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/1591319/3001761? Note `TypeError` is a possibility too. But the question isn't what can it throw so much: what can you deal with?

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe, it's very relevant indeed! I did read it beforehand, but couldn't fully make sense of [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1591432/5433628). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1591337/5433628) is an interesting solution to XY problem, but not what I'm looking for here. Perhaps the originality (as far as I can tell) of my question is that it's about a method of the standard library.

Comment: It could be a duplicate of [How to list all exceptions a function could raise in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32560116/5433628), though.

Answer (score 2):

As for the built-in functions, we need to look for them in its source code. Perhaps the easiest way is to look for CPython's unit tests, which are written in Python.

Here is the [link](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/test/test_float.py). Search for `assertRaises`.

As a side note, if `value` is guaranteed to be `str`, then it seems that `ValueError` is the only possible error.